# Using functions inside class

Tags: c++, class, declaration

C++ beginner here. I have the following code (see below) (I deleted some code for readability) I created a function to be reused inside a class, then I try to use this function inside the other function but I'm getting "duplicate symbols error" Can anyone tell me how I should define this? Do a need a main function inside this class?

```
#pragma once

#include <JuceHeader.h>
#include "Common.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

class MidiProcessor {
    
public:
    
    int samplePos, noteNumber, split1toint, split2toint;
    double calKit = 1;
    double calTrack = 1;
    char hexKit, hexTrack, hexNoteNumber, hexCheckSum, split1, split2;
    const int tracknotes[2] = {49,51};
    
    MidiMessage createSysexMessageForMe (MidiMessage midiMessage);
    
    void process(MidiBuffer& midiMessages)
    {
        processedBuffer.clear();
        MidiBuffer::Iterator it(midiMessages);
        MidiMessage currentMessage;

        while (it.getNextEvent(currentMessage, samplePos))
        {
            if (currentMessage.isNoteOnOrOff())
            {
                int trackDialValueforArray = trackDialValue -1;
                processedBuffer.addEvent(createSysexMessageForMe(currentMessage), samplePos);
                currentMessage.setNoteNumber(tracknotes[trackDialValueforArray]);
                currentMessage.setChannel(5);
            }
        }
        
        midiMessages.swapWith(processedBuffer);
    }

    MidiBuffer processedBuffer;
};

MidiMessage MidiProcessor :: createSysexMessageForMe (MidiMessage midiMessage)
{
    noteNumber = midiMessage.getNoteNumber();
    noteNumber = round((noteNumber*2.125*10.0)/10.0);
    hexNoteNumber = static_cast<char>(noteNumber);
    const auto ucx {static_cast<unsigned char>(noteNumber)};
    split1 = ucx & 0xf;
    split1toint = split1;
    split2 = ucx >> 4u;
    split2toint = split2;
    calKit = kitDialValue - 1;
    hexKit = static_cast<char>(calKit);
    calTrack = trackDialValue + 15;
    hexTrack = static_cast<char>(calTrack);
    hexCheckSum = static_cast<char>(255 - trackDialValue - 4);

    const char rawSysEx[4] = { 0x10, hexKit, hexTrack,hexCheckSum};
    
    //MidiMessage mySysEx = MidiMessage::createSysExMessage(rawSysEx,14);
    return MidiMessage::createSysExMessage(rawSysEx,14);
}
```

Comment: if this is in a header file it needs to be marked `inline`

Comment: Or just define it inside the class as is done for `process`.

Comment: One major point for good and maintainable code is to be *consistent*. If you want to define member function in a header files don't mix different styles, like you do here with some member functions defined inline in the class itself, while others are defined outside the class.

Comment: Ok, when i put the code inside the class as sugested it works, but for readability, how would i define it outside the class?

Comment: In the header file, or in a source file?

Comment: this is indeed a header file, that's being called from another source. I would like to learn how declare the functions outside of the class for readability. I indeed declare some members outside in the class because i don't know how to declare an array outside :D

Comment: If you want to define a function (member function or not) in a header file, then you need to define it as `inline`, as already mentioned. Otherwise it would be defined in all [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) where the header file included, and that breaks the one definition rule.

Comment: Sorry, inline works perfect!!! If you would have any idea on how to declare the array on top that would be awesome too. Thank you all already for your time.